# Why does my UIBarButtonItem not appear on top right corner?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have this UIViewController with this code in the .m:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *button;

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIBarButtonItem *listoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ListoBtn1.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(done:)];

    self.navBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = listoButton;

    //self.navBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = self.button;
    [self setVariables];

}
```

The button appears but it looks like this:

[image: barbuttonitem]

I just want my image to appear, not that back button.  How do I remove its border?

Comment: try to put this code in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillApear Method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the NIB hasn't completed loading when you create the button in `initWithNibName` and second your `UINavigationBar` doesn't automatically use the `navigationItem` (it's automatically used by the navigation controller). If you want to add the button to your `navBar` you should do it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: or in awakeFromNib.  or for that matter, just define the button in the nib/storyboard and let it get hooked up automatically.

Comment: Ok I moved the code to the viewDidLoad but it still doesnt show up. The navbar property is connected to the navbar in storyboard. Its not a uinavigation controller subclass, its a UIViewController subclass with a navbar dropped in.

Comment: I did get it to work by modifying it to setting the property in the navBar not in the navigationItem. The only issue left is that it shows up with the default border around it.  How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Or you could use the `customView` property on `UIBarButtonItem` and assign a `UIButton` (the one you are trying to push) to that property.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the border create your `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIButton` customView

```
UIButton *listoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *listoButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ListoBtn1.png"];
[listoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(done:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[listoButton setBackgroundImage:listoButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
listoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, listoButtonImage.size.width, listoButtonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listoButton];
self.navBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```